# Change contrast/colors, etc to multiple selected images

Tags: color, image-format

I have a simple request, but can't seem to find the answer online.

I want to change the colors of each of these green tiles to red.

When I selected all images, my Image > Adjustments tab is grey'ed out.

I know I can do this if I just merge layers, but I'd like to keep them separate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an adjustment layer like this:

1. At the bottom of the layers panel, click the adjustment layer icon ([image])
2. Choose Hue/Saturation
3. Adjust the colors

This will work for what you need to do. However, if you have layers below the adjustment layer, they will also be affected.

Comment: Well layering below the adjustment is definitely something I will be doing. Is there any other way?

Comment: I've found a solution. Place the images and an adjustment layer in a group. Then change the group's blending mode from "pass through" to "normal". Then the adjustment layer will only affect the layers in the group.